# Installing AUBit4GL via binary package

Tags: installation, 4gl

I am trying to experiment with AUBIT4GL, an Informix clone.  I am running into a problem with the process as the steps outlined in the manual and the instructions given in the `./etc/aubitrc` file seem to be a tad incomplete.

My questions are:

1. What is the purpose of the `./configure` and `./make` scripts in the distribution directory given that the software is distributed as a binary package and the install instructions make not reference to them?
2. Where is the env `TARGET_OS` set and why is there no reference to this setting in the install instructions when failing to define it causes the `aubit` program to fail?
3. Is anyone else besides me using this software or has attempted to?

Answer (score 0):

If you're running on Linux - always trying compiling from source.

If you must run from binary - you dont need to do anything with the ./configure or make.

Just point $AUBITDIR to the code.
set PATH to include $AUBITDIR/bin
set LD_LIBRARY_PATH to include $AUBITDIR/lib

and you should be good to go.

For Windows - its pretty much the same - except compiling from source is a massive pain - so use the binary ;)
There - you need to have PATH include both %AUBITDIR%/bin and %AUBITDIR%/lib

In both cases - you'll likely need to make some configuration settings (what type of database, what UI etc etc)

If you're using Informix on Linux, setting :

export A4GL_UI=TUI
export A4GL_SQLTYPE=esql

will probably be enough (if they are not defaulted in the $AUBITDIR/etc/aubitrc)